# Aggregate function not counting correctly MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I'm trying to used to pull our company sales based on a user's ID. It pulls their first/last names, their status, reps in their downline, and the most recent sale entered. It's then supposed to pull the dollar amounts for all sales and add them together (NOTE: This column was added later as a temporary fix for the sales dept.). Then for each sale, it should convert the dollar value to a point value based off the product. It should also find the total submitted and total closed point values for the sales. I only need 1 row per sales person.

Here is the current iteration of the query:

```
SELECT preps_contracted_reps.first_name AS Rep_First_Name,
    preps_contracted_reps.last_name AS Rep_Last_Name,
    preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c AS Rep_Status,
    COUNT(wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c) AS Num_Reps_in_Downline,
    MAX(opportunities.date_entered) AS Date_Entered,
    aos_products.`name` AS Product_Name,
    SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c) AS Total_in_Dollars,
    CASE 
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .125)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .833)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%'
            AND aos_products.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .166)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .333)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .33)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .16)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .025)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .625)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .625)
        ELSE opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c
        END AS All_Time_Closed_Points,
    CASE 
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .125)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .833)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%'
            AND aos_products.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .166)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .333)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .33)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .16)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .025)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .625)
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN SUM(opportunities.amount * .625)
        ELSE opportunities.amount
        END AS All_Time_Submitted_Points
FROM wn_writing_number
RIGHT JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm
    ON wn_writing_number.id = wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c
INNER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c
    ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb
INNER JOIN preps_contracted_reps
    ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
INNER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm
    ON preps_contracted_reps.id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm
    ON preps_contracted_reps.id = opportunities_cstm.preps_contracted_reps_id1_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities
    ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN aos_products
    ON opportunities_cstm.aos_products_id_c = aos_products.id
LEFT JOIN aos_products_cstm
    ON aos_products.id = aos_products_cstm.id_c
WHERE preps_contracted_reps_cstm.preps_contracted_reps_id_c = "zcrm_1130062000004859021"
    AND preps_contracted_reps.deleted = "0"
    AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Terminated"
    AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Declined"
GROUP BY preps_contracted_reps.id
ORDER BY preps_contracted_reps_cstm.preps_contracted_reps_id_c ASC,
    Last_Name ASC,
    First_Name ASC,
    Date_Entered ASC
```

Example of current output:

```
Rep_First_Name | Rep_Last_Name | Rep_Status | Num_Reps_in_Downline | Date_Entered | Product_Name | Total_in_Dollars | All_Time_Closed_Points | All_Time_Submitted_Points

          John |   Smith   |   Contracted   |        5         | 2017-12-05 14:6:41 | 12 Month Product | 393000.000000 | 245625.000000 | 233125 |
          Jane |   Doe     |  NeedsTraining |        0         | 2017-12-05 15:27:12| Null             |    Null       |    Null       |  Null  |
```

The problem that I'm having is that the Case statements aren't calculating correctly. When I go through all of the individual sales and do the calculations, I get different numbers in the `All_Time_Closed_Points` and `All_Time_Submitted_Points` columns.

I have searched through several forums and found some suggestions about it being an issue with the group by, but when I try to adjust the group by, it usually just returns 1 row with all of the information added up. Also, I have tried running several variations without the aggregate function to no avail. I did attempt to just bring back the line items, but I couldn't quite get it to bring all of the sales. It would only bring 1. Maybe because of the joins or group by? I'm at a loss of where to go next. It's a very real possibility that I'm not searching on the right keywords or that I've seen the information, but don't know how it needs to be manipulated. All help is appreciated.

EDIT: I need one of two things to happen. I either need all of the sales for each rep to calculate their total sales (which is currently correct), their total submitted points and their total closed points (neither of which are calculating correctly, currently) OR I need to return every single sale for all of the reps as well as the aos_product.`name`. When I remove the group by to pull all of the sales for individual reps, it aggregates as one rep instead of 230 with all of the stats added together. So in that respect, the group by is wrong, but I'm not sure what I should be adding next. Hopefully that helps with clarification.

EDIT 2:

```
SELECT 
    preps_contracted_reps.first_name AS Rep_First_Name,
    preps_contracted_reps.last_name AS Rep_Last_Name,
    preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c AS Rep_Status,
    COUNT(wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c) AS Num_Reps_in_Downline,
    MAX(opportunities.date_entered) AS Date_Entered,
    aos_products.`name` AS Product_Name,
    SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c) AS Total_in_Dollars,
    opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c,
    CASE 
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .125
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .833
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%' AND aos_products.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .166
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .333
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .33
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .16
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .025
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .625
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .625
        ELSE opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c
    END AS All_Time_Closed_Points,
    opportunities.amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN opportunities.amount
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .125
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .833
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%'
            AND aos_products.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .166
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .333
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .33
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .16
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .025
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .625
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN opportunities.amount * .625
        ELSE opportunities.amount
    END AS All_Time_Submitted_Points
FROM wn_writing_number 
JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number.id = wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c
JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb
JOIN preps_contracted_reps ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm ON preps_contracted_reps.id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm ON preps_contracted_reps.id = opportunities_cstm.preps_contracted_reps_id1_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN aos_products ON opportunities_cstm.aos_products_id_c = aos_products.id
LEFT JOIN aos_products_cstm ON aos_products.id = aos_products_cstm.id_c
WHERE preps_contracted_reps_cstm.preps_contracted_reps_id_c = "zcrm_1130062000004859021" AND preps_contracted_reps.deleted = "0" AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Terminated" AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Declined"
GROUP BY preps_contracted_reps.id
```

EDIT 3: The following is pulling multiple sales per rep, but not all of them. Its also putting different numbers or reps in the `Num_Reps_in_Downline` column per sale, which is interesting to me, as I would think it would just put the same total in all of the rows.

```
SELECT pcr.first_name AS Rep_First_Name,
    pcr.last_name AS Rep_Last_Name,
    pcrc.contact_status_reps_c AS Rep_Status,
    COUNT(wnc.id_c) AS Num_Reps_in_Downline,
    MAX(o.date_entered) AS Date_Entered,
    ap.name AS Product_Name,
    SUM(oc.final_sale_amount_c) AS Total_in_Dollars,
    CASE 
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .125
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .833
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%' AND ap.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .166
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .333
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .33
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .16
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .025
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .625
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .625
        ELSE oc.final_sale_amount_c
    END AS All_Time_Closed_Points,
    CASE 
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN o.amount
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN o.amount * .125
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN o.amount * .833
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%'
            AND ap.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN o.amount * .166
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN o.amount * .333
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN o.amount * .33
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN o.amount * .16
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN o.amount * .025
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN o.amount * .625
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN o.amount * .625
        ELSE o.amount
    END AS All_Time_Submitted_Points
FROM wn_writing_number wn
JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm wnc ON wn.id = wnc.id_c
JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c pcrwn ON wnc.id_c = pcrwn.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb
JOIN preps_contracted_reps pcr ON pcrwn.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = pcr.id
JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm pcrc ON pcr.id = pcrc.id_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm oc ON pcr.id = oc.preps_contracted_reps_id1_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities o ON o.id = oc.id_c
LEFT JOIN aos_products ap ON oc.aos_products_id_c = ap.id
LEFT JOIN aos_products_cstm apc ON ap.id = apc.id_c
WHERE pcrc.preps_contracted_reps_id_c = "503c4c33-d6cb-677d-0f6a-5a6f8b7aa1cc" AND pcr.deleted = "0" AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Terminated" AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Declined"
GROUP BY pcr.id, ap.name
ORDER BY pcr.last_name, pcr.first_name
```

Comment: You have that many `SELECT`, and only 1 column in `GROUP BY`?  Something is seriously wrong with your query.  You query won't even run in any other dbms.

Comment: Without looking too closely, my guess is that you probably need your CASEs inside their respective SUM(); rather than SUMs inside various WHENs. Since your CASE expressions are on non-grouped fields, you'll get the sum for whichever case value happened to have been used first.

Comment: I agree with @Uueerdo here. Correct syntax would be `SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN f1*1.26 WHEN <condition2> THEN f2 * .25 ... END) as columnalias` The way you have it written is a little oddball. I'm amazed that mysql even allows it to run.

Comment: And you should really include all of your non-aggregated fields in your GROUP BY. This query will error out in the default install of Mysql 5.7 or newer (or any other RDBMS)

Comment: Since they all appear to use the same field value; he can probably get away with `SUM( f1 * CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1.26 WHEN <condition2> THEN .25 .... END)`, using the case just to determine the multiplier for that row.

Comment: @Eric I specifically group by `preps_contracted_reps.id` because from my understanding of how group by works, it would combine all of the sales for each ID instead of giving me a line item report. @Uueerdo I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  Are you saying to actually write each of the When - Then statements individually? I was given that entire string by my boss, so I'm not entirely sure what it was written for. I'll make the suggested changes and let you all know what I find.

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer If you only grouping it by `preps_contracted_reps.id`, how do you know which `preps_contracted_reps.last_name`, or which `preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c` or which `aos_products.name` would it pick because you are aggregating your records.  It just doesn't make sense.  This query will not run in Oracle, or SQL Server, or any other dbms, because it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: The `preps_contracted_reps.id` is a primary key. There's only ever 1 `preps_contracted_reps.id` associated to an individual rep. I'm using that ID  (or trying to) to sort through the opportunities tables and pull relevant sales. @Eric See the edit to the original post.

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer It's still a good idea to list the column names, even though it will only return a single row.  There's also `aos_products.name`, which may return many rows for each `preps_contracted_reps.rep_id`.

Comment: @jNevil @Uueerod I took your advice and restructured the CASEs. This is how it looks.

`SUM(CASE WHEN aos_products.name = 'LifeSure'
THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c)
SUM(WHEN aos_products.name LIKE '%SCF%'
THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c * .125)`

Now I'm getting the following error;
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
SUM(WHEN aos_products.name LIKE '(null)CF'
THEN opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amo' at line 10"

Comment: @Eric Good point. I'll add them and see what happens.

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer What information does each table contain?  It's better to start with as few table as possible.

Comment: @Eric The `preps_contracted_reps` table contains our rep information. The `preps_contracted_reps_cstm` contains more rep information. The `wn_writing_number_cstm` contains the primary  and foreign keys to tie the `wn_writing_number` table to another table to `preps_contracted_reps` table, nothing else. `opportunites` is our sales table. `aos_products` is our products table.

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer I meant `SUM(CASE WHEN x THEN y WHEN x2 THEN y2 END)`; a `CASE` expression cannot interleave with multiple sum's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified version of your query without any `GROUP BY`.  See if it contains required records or not.

```
SELECT pcr.first_name AS Rep_First_Name,
    pcr.last_name AS Rep_Last_Name,
    pcrc.contact_status_reps_c AS Rep_Status,
    --COUNT(wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c) AS Num_Reps_in_Downline,
    wn.id_c,
    --MAX(opportunities.date_entered) AS Date_Entered,
    o.date_entered,
    ap.name AS Product_Name,
    --SUM(opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c) AS Total_in_Dollars,
    oc.final_sale_amount_c,
    CASE 
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .125
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .833
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%' AND ap.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .166
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .333
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .33
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .16
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .025
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .625
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN oc.final_sale_amount_c * .625
        ELSE oc.final_sale_amount_c
    END AS All_Time_Closed_Points,
    o.amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN o.amount
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%SCF%'
            THEN o.amount * .125
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN o.amount * .833
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%'
            AND ap.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%'
            THEN o.amount * .166
        WHEN ap.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer'
            THEN o.amount * .333
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Oil%'
            THEN o.amount * .33
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%'
            THEN o.amount * .16
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%WB%'
            THEN o.amount * .025
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%'
            THEN o.amount * .625
        WHEN ap.NAME LIKE '%Petro%'
            THEN o.amount * .625
        ELSE o.amount
    END AS All_Time_Submitted_Points
FROM wn_writing_number wn
JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm wnc ON wn.id = wnc.id_c
JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c pcrwn ON wnc.id_c = pcrwn.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb
JOIN preps_contracted_reps pcr ON pcrwn.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = pcr.id
JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm pcrc ON pcr.id = pcrc.id_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm oc ON pcr.id = oc.preps_contracted_reps_id1_c
LEFT JOIN opportunities o ON o.id = oc.id_c
LEFT JOIN aos_products ap ON oc.aos_products_id_c = ap.id
LEFT JOIN aos_products_cstm apc ON ap.id = apc.id_c
WHERE pcrc.preps_contracted_reps_id_c = "zcrm_1130062000004859021" AND pcr.deleted = "0" AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Terminated" AND contact_status_reps_c <> "Declined"
```

Comment: I used this and am still getting an error. It reads as follows;

"Unknown column 'wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c' in 'field list'

Then I went through and added it all of the full table names and got this error;

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
    CASE 
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'LifeSure'
            THEN opportun' at line 34"

Comment: Okay. So I made some changes to your query (just writing out the names on joins and such) because Navicat didn't like the abbreviations and I removed the "--"s. Was there a special reason you used the "--" before `Count, Max and Sum`? After the changes, I ran it and got back a single record with what seemed to be all of the math done in the single returned row. After adding the group by, it returned 228 records. I'll need to run the numbers and see whether the CASE counts are correct. However, It seems to be correct. See EDIT 2 and let me know what you think.

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer `--` is to comment out the line.  I removed the `GROUP BY`, so I have to remove all the aggregates.  If the raw data set looks correct, then the next step will be aggregating it.

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer It's very weird if Navicat doesn't allow table alias.  Long table names make it hard to read.  I'm pretty sure I missed to alias some columns, like the one you mentioned with `Unknown column` error.

Comment: I ended up commenting out several other lines in the original statement and it now runs. 

`SELECT pcr.first_name AS Rep_First_Name,
    pcr.last_name AS Rep_Last_Name,
    pcrc.contact_status_reps_c AS Rep_Status,
    COUNT(wnc.id_c) AS Num_Reps_in_Downline,
    MAX(o.date_entered) AS Date_Entered,
    ap.name AS Product_Name,
    SUM(oc.final_sale_amount_c) AS Total_in_Dollars,
    CASE`

Comment: Using the query in EDIT 3, I'm now getting line items for multiple sales made by each individual rep, although its not all of them. I can post a screen shot of what's actually occurring if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original query as a starting point, my comments are suggesting you need to convert to a format resembling this:

```
SUM (opportunities_cstm.final_sale_amount_c 
     * CASE 
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'LifeSure' THEN 1
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%SCF%' THEN .125
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%(PAC)%' THEN .833
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Income Select%'
            AND aos_products.NAME NOT LIKE '%(PAC)%' 
        THEN .166
        WHEN aos_products.NAME = 'Estate Enhancer' THEN .333
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Oil%' THEN .33
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Merchant Cash Advance%' THEN .16
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%WB%' THEN .025
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Land Lease%' THEN .625
        WHEN aos_products.NAME LIKE '%Petro%' THEN .625
        ELSE 1 -- ???
       END
    ) AS All_Time_Closed_Points,
```

Note: I am not quite sure about that `ELSE`. The way it was before, you were mixing `SUM` expressions with a flat field-reference.

Ideally (and required by most RDBMSes, and MySQL's more recent default configurations), aggregating queries' SELECT expressions should only consist of grouped and aggregated values.

If your SELECT contains a CASE or any logic, the logic should be based on grouped fields/values or the results of that logic should be grouped on, or be exclusively aggregated results (i.e. `SELECT CASE X WHEN 0 THEN MIN(y) ELSE MAX(y) END ... GROUP ON X`).

If the logic operates on an aggregate result it should only return an aggregate result (i.e. `SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(X) < 0 THEN MIN(Y) ELSE MAX(Y) END ...`).

If the logic is within an aggregate function, it can be used to tweak the values (as in the example above) that are being aggregated. It should go without saying you cannot include an aggregated value inside such a nested logical expression any more than you can nest one aggregate inside another.